# How to keep leading/trailing whitespaces when query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table which contains a column called dimensions which contains json value

```
dimensions
----------------
{" !":"dim_val"}
```

as you can see, the key of the json file is  `!`(leading whitespace). When I ran the query with the AS keyword

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(dimensions, "$. !") AS " !" from table
```

the colum name of the result does not contain the whitespace and only preserve the question mark

```
!
--------
"dim_val"
```

Is there a way to preserve the leading whitespace?

DB: MariaDB

Comment: If you're OK with the double quotes, you could use `JSON_EXTRACT(...) AS \`" !"\``. Looks like the output of the column name is always trimmed.

Comment: can u add some explanation about the magic between double quote and single quote?@markusjm

Comment: In order to force the field alias to be interpreted as an identifier, it must first be wrapped in backticks (not single quotes). As only leading and trailing whitespace characters are trimmed, adding the double quotes as first and last character leaves the whitespace between them alone. You could use any characters for this, it just needs to be something that isn't trimmed. For example, you could also use underscores: `JSON_EXTRACT(...) AS \`_   !_\``